# Lightning, explosions, trophy, sunglasses and more

Tags: cipher, rhyme

[image]

How to decode the above poem lines encryption for its title?

Comment: MS word memories =D

Comment: Can you provide a transcript?

Comment: lightning, explosion, explosion, trophy, sunglasses, tiledwindows, square, down, lightning, window, home, rewind, tiledwindows, tiledwindows, back  [keyboard] // window, up, fastforward, spider, lightning, sunglasses, tiledwindows, fastforward, window, up, sunglasses, tools, spider, medal, tools, tools, up, tiledwindows, back // lightning, trophy, tools, back, back, rewind, forward, up, forward, tiledwindows, up, tiledwindows, tiledwindows, speechbubbles, medal, spider, spider, down, down, back, back, tiledwindows, forward, lightning, spider, lightning, trophy.

Comment: I can't seem to understand the question. Could you clarify as to what exactly is it that you are asking?

Comment: @Sid-Asking a way to find out what is the title of the poem..there was a movie  made from this

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil- i dont know how to

Comment: @TSLF maybe you could type the message on the post - something people can copy and paste with - that's what I assumed on BeastlyGerbil's request

Comment: The characters are found (mostly fairly "early") in Microsoft's "Webdings" font, where they occupy code points used in more normal fonts for ordinary characters. The corresponding characters appear to be these: `~**%$2\`62~197223158!~$2815$@!&@@523~%@3374542522^&!!663324~!~%`. There does not appear to be any amount of shifting/rotation that makes this look much like ordinary plain text.

Comment: From above conversion-tilde,asterisk,asterisk,percent,dollar,two,grave accent,six,two,tilde,one,nine,seven,two,two,three,one,five,eight//exclamation,tilde,dollar,two,eight,one,five,dollar,at,exclamation,ampersand,at,at,five,two,three//tilde,percent,at,three,three,seven,four,five,four,two,five,two,two,caret,ampersand,exclamation,exclamation,six,six,three,three,two,four,tilde,exclamation,tilde,percent

Comment: If it is from a movie are you certain there is a solution? Sometimes they make things up for show.

Comment: @ClangorousChimera-It is not from a movie..but the title was copied from the poem

Comment: the key is shown

Comment: I don't think anyone is getting anywhere with this. Hint or self-answer?

Comment: Hint: upper right corner

Comment: Still curious about this...

Comment: @feelingferrety-Osk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took some time. But very nice idea. (Always happy to solve something that is here few months)
From transcript of picture as "Webdings" font:

> ~**%$2`62~197223158!~$2815$@!&@@523~%@3374542522^&!!663324~!~%
>  Thanks to [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan)

You look on keyboard:

> There is a picture of keyboard in "upper right corner" and another hint in comments - Osk = On Screen Keyboard. After that I realized I could use US keyboard (and not the one i have). So I found for each character - in "column" of specific number or symbol - there are 3 letters (or less for 7,8 and for 9 there is only "p"). If you have keyboard like me - type OSK in windows and turn it on for US keyboard, so for example under symbol "~" there are letters "qaz". So I "translated" text to this:
>  qaz,ol,ol,yhn,tgb,edc,qaz,ujm,edc,qaz,wsx,p,ik,edc,edc,rfv,
>  wsx,yhn,ol,wsx,qaz,tgb,edc,ol,wsx,yhn,tgb,edc,wsx,ik,edc,edc,yhn,edc,rfv,
>  qaz,yhn,edc,rfv,rfv,ik,tgb,yhn,tgb,edc,yhn,edc,edc,ujm,ik,wsx,wsx,ujm,ujm,rfv,rfv,edc,tgb,qaz,wsx,qaz,yhn,
>  You always try to find only "one correct letter" for each symbol.
>  That way I found "spider" as last word in first row, and it took few minutes to find correct form of the rest:
>  q**a**z,o**l**,**o**l,yh**n**,t**g**b,ed**c**,q**a**z,uj**m**,**e**dc,q**a**z,w**s**x,**p**,**i**k,e**d**c,**e**dc,**r**fv
>  **Along came a spider**
>  **w**sx,y**h**n,**o**l,w**s**x,q**a**z,**t**gb,e**d**c,**o**l,**w**sx,yh**n**,tg**b**,**e**dc,w**s**x,**i**k,e**d**c,**e**dc,y**h**n,**e**dc,**r**fv
>  **Who sat down beside her**
>  q**a**z,yh**n**,e**d**c,r**f**v,**r**fv,**i**k,t**g**b,y**h**n,**t**gb,**e**dc,yh**n**,**e**dc,e**d**c,uj**m**,**i**k,w**s**x,w**s**x,uj**m**,**u**jm,r**f**v,r**f**v,**e**dc,**t**gb,q**a**z,**w**sx,q**a**z,**y**hn
>  **And frightened Miss Muffet away**

Comment: Well done, necromancer!